# making shapes with Recursion in c programming

Tags: c, recursion, shapes

how can i make i c programming with recursion function shapes like in the picture below?
its a qustion from my homework. the qustion:

Write a recursive function that receives as input:

A. Closed curve (such as a circle, any polygon, ellipse);
B. Point in the curve. The function fills the territory trapped curve ("painting it") without leaving the field.

The input will contain:
1. The two-dimensional array having m rows of n characters represent the curve itself, its inner surface and its outer surface. If a different character called interval - it belongs to the closed curve.
2. pair of numbers that indicate the line number and column number that will be the point from which to start to fill the curve. Indeed, one can assume that the point is inside the closed curve.

The program runs the function to print the curve before and after filling.
There format (not absorb the user) the array with the curve in advance.

example for output: (i dont have reputation so i cant upload the picture of the example)

Comment: Are you asking about how to fill a shape? Thats what it seems like, but it is unclear.

Comment: It's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should ask for straight answers to homework (See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) stackexchange page). However, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#The_algorithm) wikipedia link contains an easy (ish...) recursive fill algorithm. It basically involves checking each pixel around a target pixel to see if it is filled. It the pixel isn't filled, it will call the recursive function on that (unfilled) pixel. If you really need the answer, I can write it for you but you should make an attempt with the flood fill algorithm first.